# Media volume suddenly became too low

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, music-player, volume, samsung-galaxy-grand

I'm using CM13 (13.0-20160716-UNOFFICIAL-i9082) for my Samsung Galaxy grand(gt-19082)

I have flashed it several times. But a few days (it worked fine for 2-3 days) after the above version was flashed, all of a sudden my media volume became too low. I have tried disabling and re-enabling my default music player. Still the problem persists.

No other volumes has been affected, and everything else is working just fine.
I can merely hear the volume when i play a song in any of my music players (tried about 3 of them).

Everything(including media volume) is perfect over the earphones.

**Edit:** The volume works fine in MX player, provided the HW+ (Hardware acceleration) is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a week, i found the answer.

**The CyanogenMod AudioFX was conflicting with the music app.** In the previous version od CM, the AudioFX could only be turned on if a headset or speaker is plugged in. But in the recent update, we can activate AudioFX for the Phone's speaker too. Thus, in my case the AudioFX was turned on (I was not aware of the update)

But the HW+ decoder of MX player overrides AudioFX, thus I was able to hear the sound while using MX player.